# Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00 - Not able to resolve

Tags: linux, kernel, raspberry-pi, init, panic

I am facing a Kernel panic from which I am not able to solve my way out. I saw some posts regarding the same but none seems to be conclusive.
I am trying on a Raspberry Pi 4B hardware to build and use my own Bootloader and Linux version.

**U-Boot: v2020.07**

**Linux Kernel: v5.8.9**

Used busybox to prepare my Root-FS which seems to be mounted, as per what I see on console. This is where I get stuck at the end:

[image]

Can you please help on what the issue could be in my case?

Comment: Your init program exited, either because it was programmed to do so or because it crashed. The kernel doesn't like that; init is supposed to run in a loop until shutdown. What are you using for init?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using the init that I got after building Busybox. I did not modify it actually.

Answer (score 1):

An update: Apparently I came across another post elsewhere which seemed to imply that busybox needs to be statically linked and not dynamic, which seemed to be the issue for me as well. I changed the build config to make it static linking and then the kernel panic disappeared.

I now am able to reach the Kernel console successfully, but I have a strange problem now. I reach /sbin/init and then the UART output to the host PC freezes. But when I connect HDMI to the Raspberry Pi, all is good and I get the console on the HDMI display.

Do you know of any solution to this problem? This seems to be reported here already but I am not sure how to solve it for my version.
[/sbin/init hangs after upgrading linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379113/sbin-init-hangs-after-upgrading-linux-kernel)

Does anyone have an idea?